# Bash floating point arithmetic with bc giving blank result?

Tags: bash, bc

I'm trying to count occurrences of a word in a text file using grep, and then multiply that result (an int) with a decimal using bc. However, the result is coming out as just a blank value (empty string I guess?).

The way I'm counting the occurrences of a word in a file is through:

```
result=$(grep -i -o "$word" $file | wc -l)
```

and then I try to do floating point math with that result through (**where `value` is a decimal**):

```
sum="value * ( $result )" | bc
```

However in the terminal, I just get blank/empty lines as the result, no values or anything. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Unless `value` can be a non-integer, there is no need for `bc` here. `wc -l` is  only going to output integers.

Comment: @chepner `value` can be a non-integer, which is why I was attempting to use `bc`, since I believe bash by itself can only do integer arithmetic

Comment: Correct; I just wanted that to be made explicit, since one answer suggests an arithmetic expression in place of `bc`.

Comment: Made that clearer in the main question, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple syntax-question. But first: did you know about the `-c` for grep? As in

```
grep -i -c  -o pattern file
```

which will save you a `wc`.

You pipe the output of

```
sum="value * ( $result )"
```

through bc. That is  not going to produce output.  You probably want to

```
sum=$(echo "183276 * $result" | bc)
```

and

```
echo $sum
```

Comment: `grep -co` only counts 1 for multiple occurrences of the same pattern in one line.

Comment: Yep; the result is the same as `grep -o | wc -l`

Comment: My point is that it's not ;) Try `grep -oc 'x' <<< $'xx\nx'` (result: 2) vs. `grep -o 'x' <<< $'xx\nx' | wc -l` (result: 3).

Comment: And a side note: The original code didn't try to pipe the output of `sum="value * ( $result )"`, but it was interpreted as an environment variable for just that command.

Comment: I did not get that last one. If I create a shel-script `mkiets` with `echo $* > iets` as content,  `sum="value * ( $result ) " | ./mkiets` creates the `iets`-file. so stdout from `sum="value * ( $result ) "` is used as input for bc.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do this using only Bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(grep -io "$word" "$file" | wc -l)
sum=$((value*result))
echo -e "$word founded $result times.\n$result * $value = $sum"
```

**Output**

```
darby@Debian:~$ word='toyota'
darby@Debian:~$ file="$HOME/Scrivania/file"
darby@Debian:~$ value=7
darby@Debian:~$ result=$(grep -io "$word" "$file" | wc -l)
darby@Debian:~$ sum=$((value*result))
darby@Debian:~$ echo -e "$word founded $result times.\n$result * $value = $sum"
toyota founded 2 times.
2 * 7 = 14
darby@Debian:~$
```

**Or a one line solution using bc**

```
darby@Debian:~$ echo "$value * $(grep -io "$word" "$file" | wc -l)" | bc
14
darby@Debian:~$
```

Comment: `echo $(command)` is the same as just `command`, you don't need to nest your one-liner like that.